# How to add a custom/dynamic target to a hyperlink

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasperreports-6.14.0.  As far as I can tell, there is only one way to add a custom hyperlink target to anything that allows hyperlinks.  **Please** tell me there is a better way (other than putting javascript into my reference expression).

1. Implement the **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHyperlinkTargetProducer** interface, looking in the hyperlink parameters for a specific, named parameter to return as your target string.
2. Extend **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter** and set its **targetProducerFactory** protected field as an instance of your new custom hyperlink target producer.

It looks like this is the only option, but it just feels like there should be a way to skip step 2 by just setting the **targetProducerFactory**.  It's almost like the Jasper devs started to do exactly that and thought "Nah, I just don't feel right about that. Let's take it out."

I am going to do the above unless some kind soul can show me a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom target producers are loaded as extensions by the HTML exporter.  You can register extensions either programmatically by creating the HTML exporter using your own `JasperReportsContext` instance, or package the extension in a jar and have it autodetected by the exporter.

If you control the HTML exporter creation you can pass the extension programmatically:

```
JRHyperlinkTargetProducer targetProducer = new JRHyperlinkTargetProducer() {            
    @Override
    public String getHyperlinkTarget(JRPrintHyperlink hyperlink) {
        return "foo";
    }
};
JRHyperlinkTargetProducerMapFactory targetProducerFactory = new JRHyperlinkTargetProducerMapFactory();
targetProducerFactory.addProducer("mycustomtarget", targetProducer);

SimpleJasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = new SimpleJasperReportsContext();
jasperReportsContext.setExtensions(JRHyperlinkTargetProducerFactory.class, 
        Collections.singletonList(targetProducerFactory));

HtmlExporter htmlExporter = new HtmlExporter(jasperReportsContext);
```

If you want to have the extension autodected you need to create a jar that contains a class like this:

```
public class CustomTargetProducerExtension implements ExtensionsRegistryFactory {
    @Override
    public ExtensionsRegistry createRegistry(String registryId, JRPropertiesMap properties) {
        JRHyperlinkTargetProducer targetProducer = new JRHyperlinkTargetProducer() {            
            @Override
            public String getHyperlinkTarget(JRPrintHyperlink hyperlink) {
                return "bar";
            }
        };
        JRHyperlinkTargetProducerMapFactory targetProducerFactory = new JRHyperlinkTargetProducerMapFactory();
        targetProducerFactory.addProducer("mycustomtarget", targetProducer);
        
        return new SingletonExtensionRegistry<>(JRHyperlinkTargetProducerFactory.class, targetProducerFactory);
    }
}
```

And put a `jasperreports_extension.properties` resource in the root of the jar containing the line:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.my.custom.target.producer=<package>.CustomTargetProducerExtension
```

Then your custom target producer would be automatically detected for elements that have `hyperlinkTarget="mycustomtarget"`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!